# Printing intermediate steps of R optimize function

Tags: r

I want to numerically optimize a function in R when derivatives are not available. I am curious how I can get printed intermediate steps of the optimization process. I know how to do it when I am using optim(). I am talking about control=list(trace...etc). How to do similar job while I am using optimize?

Answer (score 5):

Trace your objective.  Note that if you have a very old version of R you will need to upgrade to the latest for `returnValue()` to be available.

Here is the first example in `help(optimize)` with a trace added.

```
f <- function (x, a) (x - a)^2
trace(f, exit = quote(cat("x:", x, "objective:", returnValue(), "\n")), 
  print = FALSE)
optimize(f, c(0, 1), tol = 0.0001, a = 1/3)
```

giving:

```
x: 0.381966 objective: 0.002365137 
x: 0.618034 objective: 0.08105446 
x: 0.236068 objective: 0.009460549 
x: 0.3333333 objective: 0 
x: 0.3333 objective: 1.111442e-09 
x: 0.3333667 objective: 1.111442e-09 
x: 0.3333333 objective: 0 
$minimum
[1] 0.3333333

$objective
[1] 0
```